# JPA unidirectional OneToMany yields too many results

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

I'm having difficulties with an unidirectional OneToMany JPA mapping without JoinTables.

The complete entity including the nested ones looks basically like this :

```
Parent
  └ ChildLvl1
     └ ChildLvl2
        └ Attribute
```

The problem is I can insert a complex entity fine, and when I retrieve it with `repository.findAll()` it works fine and the resulting object is as expected, but when I use the api method `repository.getOne(Long)` it returns too many times the enclosed *Many* entities. The number of how many times *too many* depends on the number of attributes I insert.

So if I insert a parent with a childLvl2 with one attribute, both methods yield the same result.
But lets say I insert a childLvl2 with two attributes, the `repository.findAll()` returns the following result :

```
parent
  └ childLvl1
     └ childLvl2
        ├ attribute_1
        └ attribute_1
```

while `repository.getOne(Long)` returns the following result :

```
parent  (id=1)
  ├ childLvl1   (id=1)
  │  ├ childLvl2   (id=1)
  │  │  ├ attribute_1   (id=1)
  │  │  └ attribute_2   (id=2)
  │  └ childLvl2   (id=1)
  │     ├ attribute_1   (id=1)
  │     └ attribute_2   (id=2)
  └ childLvl1   (id=1)
     ├ childLvl2   (id=1)
     │  ├ attribute_1   (id=1)
     │  └ attribute_2   (id=2)
     └ childLvl2   (id=1)
        ├ attribute_1   (id=1)
        └ attribute_2   (id=2)
```

The (id=1) represents here the internal ID of the entity inside the database table. And indeed if I look directly in the database it contains the data I would expect, e.g. for ChildLvl1 :

```
SELECT * FROM CHILD_LVL1;

ID    | NAME  | PARENT_ID  
------|-------|-----------
    1 |  TEST |         1
```

Which shows that inside the database everything seems to be as expected, but the mapping from hibernate for the `repository.getOne(Long)` does not seem to work properly.

I have also tried this using `@OneToMany(mappedBy="xxx")` instead of `@JoinColumn` but I get the same result :-/, so I guess the error is somewhere else.

Looking at the SQL executed by hibernate I see that the two methods use different queries, `findAll()` executes multiple queries and then builds the entities, while `getOne` executes just one select with *joins*, but I really would expect the same resulting object ...

I have my entities set up like this :

```java
@Transactional
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;

    String name;
    @OneToMany(cascade= CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name="PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
    List<ChildLvl1> 

...
}
```

```java
@Transactional
@Entity
@XmlType
public class ChildLvl1 {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;

    String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name="C_LVL1_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
    List<ChildLvl2> lvl2children;

...
}
```

```java
@Transactional
@Entity
@XmlType
public class ChildLvl2 {

    @Id
    @Column(name="C_LVL2_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;

    String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade= CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name="C_LVL2_ID")
    List<Attribute> attributes;

...
}
```

```java
@Transactional
@Entity
@XmlType
public class Attribute {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;

    String key;
    String value;

...
}
```

The spring-data jpa repo :

```java
public interface ParentRepository extends JpaRepository<Parent, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Parent> {

    public List<Parent> findByName(String name);

}
```

Example usage in my testcase :

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class TestEntityCount {

    @Autowired
    ParentRepository repository;

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        if (!initialized) {
            logger.debug("Setting up repository");

            Parent parent = new Parent();
            parent.setName("TEST_PARENT");

            List<ChildLvl1> lvl1_children = new ArrayList<>();
            ChildLvl1 lvl1_child = new ChildLvl1();
            lvl1_child.setName("TEST_CHILD1");

            List<ChildLvl2> lvl2_children = new ArrayList<>();
            ChildLvl2 lvl2_child = new ChildLvl2();
            lvl2_child.setName("TEST_CHILD2");

            List<Attribute> attributes = new ArrayList<>();
            attributes.add(new Attribute("KEY1", "VALUE1"));
            attributes.add(new Attribute("KEY2", "VALUE2"));

            lvl1_children.add(lvl1_child);
            parent.setChildren1(lvl1_children);
            lvl2_children.add(lvl2_child);
            lvl1_child.setLvl2children(lvl2_children);
            lvl2_child.setAttributes(attributes);

            repository.save(parent);

            initialized = true;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindAll() {  // -> OK
        Parent parent = repository.findAll().get(0);
        logger.debug("Parent retrieved : {}", parent);
        assertEquals(1, parent.getChildren1().size());
        assertEquals(2, parent.getChildren1().get(0).getLvl2children().get(0).getAttributes().size());
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void testGetById() {  // -> java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<1> but was:<2>
        Parent parent = repository.getOne(1L);
        logger.debug("Parent retrieved : {}", parent);
        assertEquals(1, parent.getChildren1().size());
        assertEquals(2, parent.getChildren1().get(0).getLvl2children().get(0).getAttributes().size());
    }
...
```

My project uses

- Spring boot 1.5.10.RELEASE
- Spring data jpa 1.11.10.RELEASE
- hibernate 5.0.12.FINAL

I have set up an [example project @Github](https://github.com/masch82/ms-jpa-rel-test), including a testcase which demonstrates the problem in a reproducible way.

Comment: Since unfortunately I received no responses after 2 wks - I have created a bug report in the official tracker - let's see what the project says : https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1319